# Call ASP.NET MVC controller action from seperate javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, controller

What url syntax should I be using to ensure controller actions are properly resolved in a jQuery ajax call?  For example, the following syntax to invoke Method1 on HomeController works while running site in Visual Studio:

```
 $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: "Home/Method1?lparam1=" + 1+ "&param2=" + 2,  // my problem
             dataType: 'json',
             cache: false,             
             success: function(){ alert("success");}
         });
```

But when I deploy site on IIS, I get HTTP 404 telling me controller actions can not be resolved.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would let MVC generate the link for you:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Method1", "Home")?lparam1=' + encodeURIComponent(1) + ...
```

If your JS in an external file, you could set a global variable with the URL in your page and let the external file read it. Also, if your VS and IIS urls are different, you can give you site a Virtual Directory name in the project properties so that it matches your IIS directory, or better, yet, just have your project use IIS instead of Cassini (the built-in web server).

Comment: Yes, I script is external hence my problems.  When I look at url being requested it is localhost/home/method1 but under IIS, I am deploying to localhost/mysite so url should be localhost/mysite/home/method1.   Setting virtual path to mysite/ in propject properties makes VS url same as IIS but does not fix original problem.  I may just end up embedding script and call it a day.

Comment: Looks like globals is the only way to go as I will like to keep script in external file.

Comment: I think you could clean this approach up by wrapping all your logic into a JavaScript "class", and then when you instantiate it (in your page), pass in the controller URLs as options.

Comment: that is a good suggestion too.  My Javascript is either using the module or prototype pattern and so I could do what you proposed.  I now have it 'working' with a global defined as     appUrl = "http://" + window.location.host + '/myapp and propending my resource strings with this .

Answer (score 0):

Just change the url line to:

```
url: "/Home/Method1?lparam1=" + 1+ "&param2=" + 2,
```

Comment: This syntax does not work with Javascript in an external file.